# Bypass if conditions

Tags: c++

I'm working on a slot machine game. I'm having a hard time implementing wild numbers that will bypass the checks. The main problem is that wild numbers can be everywhere like at the start of a line, and a basic check like if line[1][1] == line[0][1] will not work. Any suggestion on how to make the wild number(11) bypass if conditions?

```
// Table

int slot_table[3][5] = 
{
    // Here i will do number(1,10)
    // exemple
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // Line 1
    {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, // Line 2
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, // Line 3
};

// Wild
// After the table will be crated
// This function will add randome wilds
int check_line = 0;
int wild_count = 0;
do
{
    // Rate
    if (number(1,100) <= 60)
    {
        slot_table[check_line][number(0,2)] = 11;
        ++wild_count;
    }
}
while (++check_line <= 3);
// Basic Line no. 1
// First check for first 3 numbers

if (slot_table[0][0] == slot_table[0][1] && slot_table[0][1] == slot_table[0][2])
{
    // Check for the forth one
    // 3x Win
     if (slot_table[0][1] == slot_table[0][3])
    {
        // 4x Win
        // Check for the fifth one
        if (slot_table[0][1] == slot_table[0][4])
        {
            // 5x Win
        }
    }
}
if (wild_count >= 3)
{
    // You win something
}
```

Comment: Go from left to right, find the first element that's not a wildcard and then check from left to right how many of them are this element or a wildcard. Don't forget the case when all elements are wildcards.

Comment: You mean like a check for number  int number = number(1, 10);  if number != 11 then basically I will make the number static and then check with every other numbers in table ?

Comment: You might find a function like `bool is_match(int left, int right) { return (left == WILD) or (right == WILD) or (left == right) }` helpful

Comment: The reason that `slot_table[0][0] == slot_table[0][1] && slot_table[0][1] == slot_table[0][2] && `etc works without wildcards is because equality is a [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), so you can skip some checks. You don't have a transitive relation, so you have to compare every pair.

Comment: Hmm that sounds much better than what I was considering just now

Answer (score 1):

You can count all numbers in the array by using [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and a loop. After that check the wild number and check the highest number.

Each element in `std::map` begins at zero, so you can simply increment the index without having to insert it separately.

```
#include <map>

const int row = 0;
const int wild = 11;

// Count each number and store the result in map
std::map<int, int> counter;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    counter[slot_table[row][i]]++;
}

// Final result of the game
int score = 0;

// Go through the values in the map
for (auto entry : counter) {
    const int number = entry.first;
    const int count = entry.second;
    if (count >= 3) {
        if (number == wild) {
            score = 100;
        }
        else {
            score = count * number;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what I'm making I need to insert it separately. And I do not need to count numbers but I need to compare them. Based on Caleth's suggestion I will do a bool pair(int x, int y) and I will compare pair by pair.